# Вложенные комментарии в django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Пытаюсь сделать вложенные комментарии к постам, но при выводе постов выдает ошибку: "столбец news_comment.parent_id не существует". Сделать миграцию не помогает. Как решить эту проблему или, возможно, стоит сделать все иначе?

### serializers.py

```
        class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
              replys = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

              def get_replys(self, obj):
                    queryset = Comment.objects.filter(parent_id=obj.id)
                    serializer = CommentSerializer(queryset, many=True)
                    return serializer.data

              class Meta:
                model = Comment
                fields = '__all__'
```

```
        class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
                comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

                def get_comments(self, obj):
                    queryset = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=obj.id, parent_id=None)
                    serializer = CommentSerializer(queryset, many=True)
                    return serializer.data

                class Meta:
                    model = Post
                    fields = '__all__'
```

### models.py

```
        class Comment(models.Model):
            post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
            parent = models.ForeignKey(
              'self',
              default=None,
              blank=True,
              null=True,
              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
              verbose_name='parent',
              related_name='replys'
            )
            text = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
            date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
            username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ошибка в строке:

`queryset = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=obj.id, parent_id=None)`.

Если разбирать ошибку "столбец news_comment.parent_id не существует". То он ругается на parent_id в фильтрации.  Я понимаю, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к неявному столбуц parent_id, но я не уверен что он создается учитывая то, что в ForeignKey вы связываете его с собой ("self"). Попробуйте изменить фильтры.
Для удобства работы с Django ORM можно использовать Django Shell:

`python3 manage.py shell`
Потом импортируете нужные Models (`from <app_name>.models import Comments`) и смотрите их атрибуты и поля.

Comment: Я бы мог дать более полный ответ, если бы увидел  модель Post